# Using Custom middleware in standalone scrapy script

Tags: python, scrapy

I am writing a standalone scraping script (update.py) that implements a custom downloader middleware.

The script is currently using the CrawlerProcess() API documented [here](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/api.html#crawler-api) and [here](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/practices.html).

It looks something like this:

```
from scrapy.crawler import CrawlerProcess
import scrapy

class CustomMiddleware(object):
.... custom middleware definition

settings = {'LOG_LEVEL' :'INFO',
            'COOKIES_ENABLED' : False,
            'DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES' : {
            'update.CustomMiddleware': 400,
            }
            }

class CarvanaSpider(scrapy.Spider)
... Spider definition

process = CrawlerProcess(settings)
process.crawl(CarvanaSpider)
process.start()
```

The script returns the error: "No module named 'update'"

If I replace update.CustomMiddleware with CustomMiddleware it returns 'Not a valid path'

I am aware of the get_project_settings() utility but my script cannot be in a project folder and must be able to run without any additional files.

Is this achievable?, if so what is the best way to achieve this?

Comment: Tried '.CustomMiddleware' ?

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. In the past year I have given up on this problem and cannot find the dir I was working on so can't test this. If anyone else stumbles on the same problem, let us know if this suggestion works.

Answer (score 0):

you need separate middleware file and import middleware on top of the script.

class CustomMiddleware(object):
.... custom middleware definition

this class will be in middleware.py

and in settings only add like this

```
settings = {'LOG_LEVEL' :'INFO',
            'COOKIES_ENABLED' : False,
            'DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES' : {
            'middleware.CustomMiddleware': 400,
            }
            }
```

and both middleware.py and you script both in the same directory.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion but as detailed in the question I was looking for a solution that does not require any additional files (e.g. middleware.py).

Comment: ohh then you put this class in same file 
class ```class CustomMiddleware(object):
    def process_request(self, request, spider):
        proxy_list = []
        request.meta['proxy'] = "https://"+random.choice(proxy_list)```
and in process = CrawlerProcess(

```CrawlerProcess({'LOG_ENABLED': True, 'CONCURRENT_REQUESTS':100,
'DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES': {
 'update.CustomProxyMiddleware': 500,
                            },
                        })```
this will work for me


first put this class and then put you spider code and last put this settings...